# Cannot run my codes for sending email in other machine

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I am helping my friend to develop her codes using VBA. I have successfully run these codes in my laptop yet she is encountering errors when we copy the codes to her machine.

Here's my code:

```
Sub Test()

    Call sendingEmailWithChecklist("Book1.xlsm")

End Sub

Sub sendingEmailWithChecklist(workbookName As String)

    Dim recipient As String
    Dim cc As String
    Dim subject As String
    Dim body As Range
    Dim greetings As String
    Dim message As String
    Dim signature As String
    Dim ebody As String

    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olInsp As Outlook.Inspector
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim olEmail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim worksheetName As String
    Dim content As Range

    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set olEmail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    Sheet2.Activate

    recipient = Range("B3").Value
    cc = Range("B4").Value
    subject = Range("B5").Value

    greetings = Range("B6").Value
    message = Range("B7").Value

    ebody = greetings & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & message & vbNewLine

    signature = Range("B8").Value

    'Workbooks(workbookName).Activate
    worksheetName = "Sheet1"


    With olEmail
        .Display

        .To = recipient
        .cc = cc
        .subject = subject

        Set olInsp = .GetInspector
        Set wdDoc = olInsp.WordEditor

        Workbooks(workbookName).Worksheets(worksheetName).Activate

        Workbooks(workbookName).Worksheets(worksheetName).Cells.Copy

        'Range("A1:F17").Select
        'Selection.Copy

    End With

    With olEmail

        .Display
        wdDoc.Range(1, 1).Paste
        wdDoc.Range.InsertBefore ebody

        '.Send


    End With

End Sub
```

`wdDoc.Range(1,1).Paste` was her error. We have both declared same references from tools yet the error is still on this line. What could be the possible error why it doesn't run on her machine?

PS. She doesn't want to use `HTMLbody`.

Comment: Why do you have 2 `With olEmail`?

Comment: I have already deleted 1 with olEmail   but still it didn't fix our error.

Comment: As [stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47446571/2685412) by @tlemaster, changing it to `wdDoc.Range.Paste` makes your code work at my end. It also paste `ebody` before the copied Range. `It didn't give us the outcome that we want `. Please be specific of the issue and error you get for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
wdDoc.Range(1, 1).Paste
```

Try

```
wdDoc.Range.Paste
```

Comment: The text from my ebody was pasted in the first cell of my range. It didn't give us the outcome that we want

Answer (score 0):

If you want to further control the way you paste your data in the body of mail you may want to use the Word `Selection` object (expression) instead of `Range`. Something like:

```
wdDoc.Application.Selection.PasteAndFormat wdFormatOriginalFormatting
```

Above paste the copied item with its original formatting.
 You may select other `PasteAndFormat` options depending on your expected outcome.

Comment: @RouellaMayGabineteAmponin What error and what line?

Comment: on that line. wdDoc.Application.Selection.PasteAndFormat wdFormatOriginalFormatting

Comment: @RouellaMayGabineteAmponin what is the error msg? are you sure you have the correct reference set?